# How do I count correctly processes created by fork?

Tags: c, fork

I am having problems with C code about processes that are created with fork given by our professor to figure out the number of processes that it creates.

```
pid1 = fork();

if (pid1 != 0) {
   pid2 = fork();
   pid3 = fork();
}
else {
   pid4 = fork(); 
}
```

Comment: What problem? What have you tried to solve it?

Comment: I have tried to run the code with some printf at the end of every fork, to try to figure out how to create the processes tree that we were asked for.

Comment: And how did that go? Did you get stuck at some particular point? If so, please include your thought process in your question. We need to see your attempt at solving your problem.

Comment: Instead of a bunch of variables consider using an array.

Answer (score 2):

Running the code is only somewhat helpful (and can't be done during the exam!)--better to draw a process tree. The rules are that every child process starts execution after the `fork` call that spawned it, parents have nonzero `pid` and children have a `pid` of zero.

```
         main
       /   |   \
    pid1 pid2 pid3
     /     |
  pid4   pid3
```

We can see `main` spawns three children, `pid1`, `pid2` and `pid3` (`pid1` is trivial and the other two are spawned in the true `if` block). `pid1` goes on to the `else` portion of the conditional and spawns `pid4` before finishing. `pid2` is the only trick: it spawns again at `pid3` because that's where its execution starts.

Answer:

> 6 processes in total are created (`main` and 5 children)

Comment: Your count is right, but your tree is wrong.  You appear to have gotten the sense of the condition backward.  `pid1 != 0` is true in the parent, not the child.

Comment: That is very helpful, I was having a similar confusion about the two fork () inside the if. But, now I think I got a clearer view abou it especially pid3. Thank you